# Neo4j-spring-data(4.1.1) self relationship (parent-child) is duplicated

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I am using spring-data-4.1.1 & Neo4j 2.3.2 with ogm annotations

Below is my entity

```
    @NodeEntity(label = "Component")
    public class Component extends BaseEntity {
    .........

      @Relationship(type = Relation.LINK_TO)
      private Set<Link> links = new HashSet<>();

      @Relationship(type = Relation.PARENT)
      private Set<Component> parents = new HashSet<>();
    .........
    .........


}
```

And Link class

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = Relation.LINK_TO)
public class Link extends BaseEntity {

    @Property(name = "isSelfLink")
    private boolean isSelfLink;

    @StartNode
    private Component component;

    @EndNode
    private Component linkComponent;
}
```

I've removed getter/setter/hashcode/equals for keeping it clean

Now, here is my code to add two component parent/child and a Link

```
Component parentcomp = new Component(1, name);
Component childcomp =  new Component(2, name);
childcomp.getParents().add(parentcomp);

Link link = new Link();
link.setComponent(parentcomp);
link.setLinkComponent(childcomp);
parentcomp.getLinks().add(link);

componentRepository.save(parentcomp,-1);
```

Now, as per the logic

1. object parentcomp property 'parent' should be empty
2. object childcomp property 'parent' should have parentcomp object
3. And parentcomp property 'links' should have childcomp

   (parentcomp)----LINKS_TO---->(childcomp)

   (parentcomp)<----PARENT----(childcomp)

Note: My equirement is such that we need two way relationship..

But, below is the result when I load parent or child entity

1. object **parentcomp** property 'parent' has both childcomp,parentcomp instead of empty
2. object **childcomp** property 'parent' has both childcomp,parentcomp instead of only parentcomp

This behavior persist until a Neo4j sessions clears out internally. After some time(or after app restart) the mappings shows up correctly.

I tried cleaning up the session using neo4joperations.clear() still problem persists. But if I query

```
match (c:Component)-[:PARENT]->(p) where c.componentId = {0} return p
```

results are correct.

I am not sure how to solve this problem...

Comment: Which version of SDN 4 and which version of neo4j-ogm are you using?

Comment: I am using sdn 4.1.1 hooper train release and neo4j-ogm  version is 2.0.1, it is pulled along with sdn4.

Comment: k, could you please open an issue at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues with a simple test case?